# MSBuild - Error: Create XML Report

Tags: xml, unit-testing, msbuild, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm new to MSBuild stuff and have to write a msbuild-File which starts my Unit tests. This is my Code and it works, except one thing.

[Code - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b1jY.png)

So this Code works, but if I add /xml=@(TestResultsPath) to the Line:

```
<Exec Command='"@(NUnitConsole)" "@(UnitTestsDLL)" ' />
```

So that it looks like:

```
<Exec Command='"@(NUnitConsole)" "@(UnitTestsDLL)" /xml="@(TestResultsPath)" ' />
```

I get a error. Does sb know how to fix that? If I don't add the line, it creates automatically the report in the same Folder where MyCalculator.sln is, but I want to have the report in the Directorie "BuildArtifacts"

Comment: What error? Do you know the documentation doesn't mention a /xml option? https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Comment: Hey. I found the /xml in this tutorial: [link]https://www.infoq.com/articles/MSBuild-1 But I guess its wrong, like you said.

The Error says that the notation is wrong but I cant find another way
Thats the screenshot of the error [link]http://imgur.com/a/Wjz8f

Comment: Note the error message doesn't display `/xml` but just `xml` which is definitely wrong. I don't have nunit to test but you should be able to figure this out yourself. Look up what the correct command line option is then try to use that.

Comment: Heeeeeeeeeey:) I fixed it!!! I'm so happy. I asked the wrong way but yeah...I found the solution on this side: [link]http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3
under the headline "Specifying a Directory for Output".

/xml is an old notation for changing the name of the xml-file.
**What I need is /work:BuildArtifacts**

Comment: You tagged this as both nunit and nunit-3.0, so I assume you are using NUnit 3.x. Yet you are referencing NUnit V2 documentation. If you are using V3, use the V3 docs. If you are using 2.6.4, use 2.6.4 docs... and so on, substituting 2.6.3, 2.6.2, etc. all the way back to 2.0! :-)

Note that google is really not your friend in this, since we have chosen to keep the old docs around. Start at the top of the website and navigate to the docs you want.

Comment: yeah you are right! Thanks! I changed it now into **--work=BuildArtifacts**